# squid commSetConnTimeout

Tags: squid, timeout

I'm using squid 3.5.20 on centos.
I send a curl request to bigquery directly without a squid proxy, and I have a response after 8 minutes.

Now, when I launch the same curl request through the squid proxy, I have a response after 15 minutes.

When I set debugging mode on squid, I can see a timeout of 900 during the tunnel.

"comm.cc(553) commSetConnTimeout: local=10.190.113.69:50488 remote=74.125.193.153:443 FD 11 flags=1 timeout 900"

Is it possible to change this timeout under squid ?